# Error "The network path was not found" on joining a domain

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to join my windows 7 desktop to our companies domain. The domain is all set up and other win7 boxes are joined to the domain OK. When I try to join the domain, I get prompted for credentials, I enter the valid credentails, and then get the error  "The network was was not found".

It seems that DNS servers are a common cause of this, so on IPConfig /all I can see I have a valid looking connection-specific DNS suffix, and I have 2 IPs in my DNS servers list (the same as another PC I looked at that is on the domain). I changed the ipv4 config to explicitly use these DNS server IPs rather than obtain automatically, to no avail.

I can access computers on the network (I get prompted for credentails which then works), its just joining the domain that doesn't work.

I'm not very skilled at AD / network issues so it might be something obvious ;)

[UPDATE]

It seems that we're using google public DNS (8.8.8.8) instead of one on our server. So the problem is likely to be that when trying to join the domain, the computer is using google to try and find the server FQN - which it isn't going to find. Is there a way round this? I tried changing the DNS server to the IP of the server, but it doesn't like that.

Answer (score 1):

Then you'll want to setup Googles DNS Servers as 'Forwarders' inside the AD DNS Settings, so that way anything your servers can't resolve, Google DNS will take over.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754941.aspx -- This link will walk you through that process.

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of the connection specific DNS suffix.

Second, is your machine configured to use the DNS servers that are responsible for the AD DNS zone? It's hard to tell from what you've stated.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit lame with this. I unticked "append parent suffixes of primary DNS servers" but that doesn't appear to remove the suffix. As for the AD DNS zone, I asusme that is the case because I checked a PC that is on the domain, and is using the same DNS servers (it also has 127.0.0.1 which I assume I don't need to worrry about)

Comment: Where are you seeing the DNS suffix, in the "DNS suffix for this connection" field? If so, just delete it from that field.

Comment: No I only see that when I issue "ipconfig /all" - I don't see it anywhere else..

Comment: OK, it sounds like this is being set by the DHCP server then. Does the DNS suffix in ipconfig/all match the AD DNS suffix?

Comment: Yeah, they match...

Comment: OK, and you're sure that the NIC is using the AD DNS server for DNS?

Comment: It seems we're using google DNS servers - I've edited the original question with more information...

Comment: THE AD DNS server should point to itself for DNS and the AD clients should point to the AD DNS server for DNS. That's the only way it's going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check: ensure NetBIOS over TCP/IP is enabled on the server.  Disabling this prevented me from adding new machines in the domain

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue - rebooting fixed it. Here's the details:

- Server had dropped off domain
- Logged in as local admin, joined server to WORKGROUP
- Attempted to rejoin the domain (without rebooting) - error "Network Path was not found"
- `IPCONFIG /ALL` showed a valid DNS server
- Could `ping domain.local` OK
- `NSLOOKUP domain.local` OK
- Rebooted and was able to join the domain with no issues

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. We were using Firewall as the DHCP server and we had made a mistake in the settings. I manually provided IP address to the client and it worked like a charm. I am going to change DHCP settings now.